# Newest transactions added on top, not bottom, of accounts in GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash, double-entry

In GnuCash, with ascending date the transactions are listed from top to bottom.

Is there a way to have the transactions listed with ascending date from bottom to top? I.e. I want the newest transaction to be the first in the list, not the last!

Reason: all other tables I use for my finances (bank, credit card statements, etc) have the newest transaction always added on top of the list. And in the long run it can get very confusing and tiresome, especially if I have to type in (copy) lists of transactions into GnuCash, which I can not import and have to copy by typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the account register using the `View->Sort By` menu choice. However, there doesn't appear to be a preference to have this happen all the time.

There is no way to have the blank entry appear anywhere but at the bottom of the register.

Comment: I am using two Japanese banks, I don't think I have a check register or book, but my online banking and monthly statements are always so that the newer the date, the higher in the list. Just to qualify because you write that "...as it would be in a check register or a book". I don't think this is true for all banks, all over the world - and international support is supposed to be one of the strong points of GC. Anyway thank you for this answer.

Comment: You bring up a good point, I was talking about only my own experience. I'm not sure what accounting books look like in other countries either; I will remove that part of the answer.